# iframe .contents doesn't find content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a page as an iframe and then extract some information from it.

```
function calleniro(who, where, announcementID){
    var url = 'https://personer.eniro.se/resultat/'+who+'/'+where;
    var frameid=announcementID.substr(0,7)
    var iframe=$('<iframe />', {
        src: url,
        id: frameid
    }).appendTo('body');
    iframe.load(function (){

        var frame = $('#'+frameid).contents;
        console.log(frame)
    });
}
```

the  `console.log($(frameid))` renders the iframe-node as desierd, when I add content it seems to be not find anyting

```
var frame = $(frameid).contents().find('body');
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: is the iframe's url in the same domain as the parent document?

Comment: nope! does it have to be?

Comment: I believe so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot interact with content outside of your domain.

If your only intent is to load the page to get values from it (i.e not actually display the IFrame) you could simply `$.get()` the Eniro url to get the raw HTML response and then parse it from there. I think that should be possible with jQuery, might require some tinkering though :)

**Update**
As has been pointed out, the same origin policy applies to my solution as well (learning something new every day!), however it should be perfectly possible to apply the solution at the server instead

Comment: thanks for the answer, allthough, the same origin policy apply to that aswell. I ended up making a php-proxy http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/examples/simple/

Comment: Ah! I was certain this was possible! My mistake! Must have confused it with something else I did, glad you found a solution though!

Comment: You post to a offsite server, but that's pretty much it.